# difficulty using mayavi in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, mayavi

I'm using python 3.5 on windows, and following a tutorial about mayavi, which is using python 2.7, according to the previous experiences I have, version should not be a BIG obstacle, but turns out it is a BIG obstacle. Here's a simple test code:

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
t = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 50)
x = np.sin(2 * t)
y = np.cos(t)
z = np.cos(2 * t)
s = 1 + np.sin(t)
mlab.points3d(x, y, z, s)
```

And that's what I got(My folder name is erased)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\PlotsPartOne.py", line 602, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:\...\PlotsPartOne.py", line 590, in Main
    mayaviTest()
  File "C:\...\PlotsPartOne.py", line 582, in mayaviTest
    mlab.points3d(x, y, z, s)
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mayavi-4.5.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py", line 37, in the_function
    return pipeline(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mayavi-4.5.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\mayavi\tools\helper_functions.py", line 77, in __call__
    scene = tools.gcf().scene
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mayavi-4.5.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\mayavi\tools\figure.py", line 113, in gcf
    engine = get_engine()
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mayavi-4.5.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 101, in get_engine
    return self.new_engine()
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mayavi-4.5.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 146, in new_engine
    check_backend()
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mayavi-4.5.0-py3.5-win-amd64.egg\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 49, in check_backend
    ''')
ImportError: Could not import backend for traits
_______________________________________________________________________________
Make sure that you have either the TraitsBackendWx or the TraitsBackendQt
projects installed. If you installed Mayavi with easy_install, try
easy_install <pkg_name>. easy_install Mayavi[app] will also work.

If you performed a source checkout, be sure to run 'python setup.py install'
in Traits, TraitsGUI, and the Traits backend of your choice.

Also make sure that either wxPython or PyQT is installed.
wxPython: http://www.wxpython.org/
PyQT: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro
```

And I am pretty sure that I have installed wxPython, traits and PyQt(version 5), but am not sure whether TraitsBackendWx or TraitsBackendQt is installed, I searched, and didn't find any package available for python 3... But sence mayavi has a python 3 version, there's got to be a way to run mayavi code on python 3(I suppose...) . So, any way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TraitsBackendWx, TraitsBackendQt, Traits, TraitsGUI, Traits backend, wxPython or PyQT I don't lack any of these packages, what I need is a PySide package...

```
pip install PySide-1.2.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

The package (by a 3rd party, be warned) is located at https://github.com/krrr/PySide/releases/download/1.2.4-1/PySide-1.2.4-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl.

Comment: You are free to accept your own answer if it solved it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I get it work in ubuntu by : 
  sudo apt-get install python3-pyside

other modules related are :
vtk  8.1.0
mayavi  4.5.0
python  3.5.2